# Are there standards or guidance for the placement and location of rest areas on newly constructed or designated U.S. Interstates?

Tags: design, highway-engineering

As the highway engineers here may already know, U.S. highway 71 through most of Missouri was recently redesignated as a section of Interstate 49 after the completion of grade separation work at several locations.  However, having been on the road recently, I noticed one thing that is missing from it that most rural Interstates have: rest areas.  While private facilities are available at most exits from that stretch of road, the lack of rest areas on an over 100 mile stretch of road when most Interstates have them at roughly 50 mile intervals strikes me as an oversight by MoDOT, and left me wondering if it was a substandard highway for that reason alone.  Furthermore, I reviewed the 2017-2021 Transportation Improvement Plan for the MoDOT Southwest District, and there were no projects in there to add rest areas to I-49.

So, are there any standards or guidance materials for the placement/location of rest areas (with or without services) on newly constructed or designated rural Interstates?  Or can a highway be built or upgraded to "Interstate standard" without such provisions without drawing a peep from standards or guidance material?

Comment: [This article](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/travel_explainer/2015/08/rest_stop_distance_how_is_the_placement_of_rest_areas_on_highways_decided.html) from Slate might provide an interesting starting point for your research.